# Unable to locate Jenkins file when Jenkins is installed over Tomcat on Linux Machine

Tags: jenkins

Unable to locate Jenkins file when Jenkins is installed over Tomcat on Linux Machine

I have installed Jenkins(Jenkins.war) on a Linux (RedHat) machine using Tomcat application server.Prior to installation I had set my JENKINS_HOME(in ~/.bash_profile) to /apps/jenkins folder so that Tomcat will install Jenkins on this directory.

Post installation Jenkins is up and running and my jobs are executing fine.However, I need to change JENKINS_USER to other user but I am not able to locate the Jenkins file that will have info like JENKINS_USER and JENKINS_PORT.
I tried searching this file under following directories but no success.

```
/var/lib/jenkins 
/etc/sysconfig 
/etc/default
```

I am not able to find it even in the Jenkins installation directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files you are searching are only found in the standalone installations of Jenkins through various package managers of different supported Linux distributions for which Jenkins offers packages.

The install of `Jenkins` in Tomcat is just downloading and copying `jenkins.war` in Tomcat's `webapps` folder as a servlet, everything else is managed through Tomcat config files, like setting `JENKINS_HOME` or changing the port by editing the connector `xml` for example.

The documentation on running Jenkins as a `.war` in Tomcat is [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Tomcat). You can see examples on how to change the connector port in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml` and also `JENKINS_HOME` in the context. I assume you understand at least how Tomcat works and how to configure it.

Comment: Thanks for the response mate. I can say I have a fair understanding of Tomcat and its configuration settings.
Earlier, when I installed Jenkins as a standalone install I was able to locate the Jenkins file, but had a hard time later when installed it as a servlet in Tomcat.
Thanks for highlighting that the availability of this particular config file depends on the way we are installing Jenkins.